# Triangle, vectors, hard to explain

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-analysis

P is the middle of a median line from vertex A, of ABC triangle. If Q is the point of intersection of lines AC and BP. Find relations of $|\vec{AQ}|$/$|\vec{QC}|$ and $|\vec{BP}|$/$|\vec{PQ}|$

[image]

Any suggestions for the title, welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

We have $M=\tfrac12(B+C)$,
$P=\tfrac12(A+M)$

Expressions for the points 
on the lines $AC$ and $BP$ in parametric form are:

\begin{align}
p_{AC}(s)
&=
(1-s)\cdot A+s\cdot C,
\\
p_{BP}(t)
&=
(1-t)\cdot B+t\cdot P.
\end{align}

Since $Q=AC \cap BP$,
\begin{align}
Q&=
p_{AC}(s)
=
p_{BP}(t),
\\
(1-s)\cdot A+s\cdot C
&=
(1-t)\cdot B+t\cdot P.
\end{align}
The last one gives a linear system 
of two equations (for $x$ and $y$ coordinates)
in two unknowns $s$ and $t$,
with solution 
$s=\tfrac13$,
$t=\tfrac43$ and then the answer is

\begin{align}
\frac{|AQ|}{|QC|}&=\tfrac12
\\
\frac{|BP|}{|PQ|}&=3.
\end{align}